# Convert ereg_replace to preg_replace in USAePay source code

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using USAePay's [horrible] PHP library to connect to their gateway, but I'm getting the following error:

> Deprecated: Function ereg_replace() is deprecated in .../usaepay.php on line 320

This corresponds to the following line:

```
$this->amount = ereg_replace("[^[:digit:].]", "", $this->amount);
```

So, I'd like to switch it out with `preg_replace`.
Here's what I'm thinking:

```
$this->amount = ereg_replace("/[^[\d].]/", "", $this->amount);
```

Is this equivalent to the one above, or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to delete any non-digit or non-period character from the string that represents an amount. You can do:

```
$this->amount = preg_replace("/[^\d.]/", "", $this->amount);
```

Regex used:

```
[   - Start of character class
 ^  - Negation
 \d - any digit
 .  - a literal perios
]   - end of character class
```

Comment: Is `[:digit:]` in `ereg` equivalent to simply `\d` in `preg`?

Comment: Actually, PCRE also support the [:digit:] character class (see [this link](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php)). And yes, they both mean the same thing

Comment: You should use single quotes for regex strings. Otherwise you might accidentally use some escape sequence instead of a raw `\something`.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to grab the latest version of the usaepay library:

https://github.com/usaepay/usaepay-php

which replaces the line in question with:

```
$this->amount=preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/","",$this->amount);
```

Comment: `'/[^\d.]/'` is nicer (no need to escape the dot inside a character class)

Comment: any particular reason you like \d more than 0-9?  there is no difference in speed and I think 0-9 is a little more obvious.  if you really want to go the \d route,  why not do \D instead of ^\d.  Also,  I think using a \.  thoughout the pattern (including inside brackets) is a good idea.  less likely to mistakenly forget the slash when you are outside the brackets which could lead to unexpected pattern matching...

Comment: Personally I prefer `0-9` when I need a character class anyway - but `\d` is still "cleaner" IMO. `\D` won't work due to the `.` you also want to allow.

Comment: `+1` I actually filed a bug on this, and they redirected me to their GitHub repository...

Comment: Yea, its really frustrating that they don't have the most recent version linked on their developer library - that would have saved me some time